# Providing a Dev-Cert for an ASP.Net Core 3.1 project running in Docker?

Tags: docker, ssl, asp.net-core

When running my ASP.Net Core 3.1 web app in IISExpress the Dev-Cert I have in place is found and used to provide HTTPS, but when I try to run the same app on the same machine but in a Docker Windows container the certificate is not found.

I assume there are some steps needed to make the certificate visible in the Docker container but I've not been able to find anything current discussing this.

What needs to be done to get a Dev https app running in a Windows Docker container? (running from Visual Studio 2019)

Comment: This may help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Searched all over and didn't run across this. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.